# Position cursor in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I would like to position the cursor in an AlertDialog right after the value I display in setView. So, when value is "2.40", the cursor should position itself right after the 0. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
final EditText input = new EditText(co);
TextView tx= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_accrued);//3.0.7
input.setText( (String) tx.getText());
new AlertDialog.Builder(co)
.setTitle("whatever")
.setMessage("Total amount including tip")
.setView(input)
 aso....
```

Comment: You can use a TextWatcher on your EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about

```
final EditText input = new EditText(co);
TextView tx= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_accrued);
input.setText( (String) tx.getText());
int position = input.length();
Selection.setSelection(input, position);
```

or

```
input.setSelection(position);
```

also use `tx.getText().toString()` instead of `(String) tx.getText())` ... its nicer and more clear...